# md menu with search closes the md menu on search - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material, haml

I'm trying to create an md menu with nested md menu along with search input (See the attached image).
When I search for a particular item, md menu closes. I have added 
`md-prevent-menu-close="md-prevent-menu-close"` in element but it doesn't work.

[image]

Thanks in advance.!